# Mountain house in "Harvest Moon: Light of Hope"

Tags: harvest-moon-light-of-hope

In the game *Harvest Moon: Light of Hope* (for the Nintendo Switch), there is a house on the mountain which, so far, can not be entered. Doc's house is on top, next level down is the hot springs, and then this random circular house that can't be entered.

Here's the house circled on the map:

[image: Farm: Western Area]

I can't find anything, anywhere talking about this house. I can't enter it, no one ever goes in it. What is the point of this thing?

I have already beaten the main storyline, and repaired all the houses I could find. This mystery house never came up.

Answer (score 1):

It’s Nova’s house..  -space filler since I need 30 characters- *rolls eyes*

Comment: Thanks! Did they say that at some point and I just missed it? I've never seen her in there.

Answer (score 1):

Nova's house. You can see it in her off days from her summer beach shop. [image]